# what is the easiest way to migrate my wordpress site from one hosting provider to another?

Tags: wordpress

i have a windows hosting provider and i am moving to another one.  what is the best way to migrate a wordpress blog from one hosting provider to another ?

Comment: Are you moving into another windows hosting provider?

Comment: @Ruel - yes, i am moving to another windows hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) provides plenty of information on the topic of moving a Wordpress.
If you don't feel like reading through all of that, [here](http://yoast.com/move-wordpress-blog-domain-10-steps/) is a far shorter guide, that covers essentially the same method.